# "as in" or "as with"?

Tags: prepositions

> In FIG. 1, object A is omitted for the sake of brevity. ... In FIG.
>   10, **as in/with** FIG. 1, object A is omitted for the sake of
>   brevity.

I would like to know which of **as in/with** is correct in the sentence above I created, although you may think the phrase "**as in/with FIG. 1**" is redundant and unnecessary. The result of google search I made indicates both are used almost equally.

Comment: I'm not answering this, but I would simply say in fig 10, _like_ in Fig 1.

Comment: Like you, I sometimes use like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking whether to use "**as in**" or "**as with**" is *exactly the same* as asking whether you should use "**in**" or "**with**".

In documentation, a numbered 'figure' is normally a picture or a diagram. So, would you say that something is *in* a picture, or *with* a picture?

You would say that something was "in" a picture.

So, you should say "*as **in** FIG. 1*"